# Chrome: Unexpected identifier , Firefox: missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, syntax-error, flot

The following is triggering a syntax error (`unexpected identifier` in Chrome, and `missing ] after element list` in Firefox):

```
infowindow.setContent('<h3>'+locale+' ('+hour+':00): $'+s.total+'</h3><img src="'+fname+'" onclick="open_dialog('+flot_data+');" style="cursor:pointer;" />');
```

Specifically, the `'+flot_data+'` in `onclick="open_dialog('+flot_data+');"`. Removing this bit removes the syntax error.

Firebug points (literally) to `flot_data` which it represents with `[object Object]` (it points to the `O` in the second `Object`. The json was generated by PHP's `json_encode`, so I don't think the json is malformed (also I am elsewhere in this app able to successfully operate on all the parts of this object that I'm trying to use here).

I tried leaving in the onclick and commented out the contents of my `open_dialog` function to ensure the syntax error isn't triggered inside it. And, I tried copying the contents of my `open_dialog()` function directly into the onclick like so:
    `onclick="$.plot($(\'#graph\'),'+flot_data+');"`
(the onclick is encased in `''` and uses `""`, so I had to use escaped single quotes)

I copy/pasted the data being passed to `setContent` and validated it in a fiddle. Why is the syntax incorrect here but not in the validation?

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML, specifically `onclick="open_dialog('+flot_data+');"`. The result (`"open_dialog('+flot_data+');`) does not seem to be valid JavaScript and by looking at it you will probably figure out why not. We cannot help you more unless you tell us what the value is of `flot_data`.

Comment: @FelixKling the value of `flot_data` is a very large data object / json (not excessive, but too large to post here). btw, I use `flot_data` elsewhere so there's not a syntax error in it. I'm not sure what you mean "look at the generated HMTL"—there's no generated HTML as the script does not execute.

Comment: This line is concatenating a string and passing it to `setContent`. Are you saying that this line is not executed and the content is never set? Because the string concatenation itself looks fine to me. It seems more that the resulting `open_dialog(...);` is invalid JS, i.e. you get the error when you try to click on the image. Btw, if `flot_data` is really an object, then you don't want to concatenate it with a string, since the result would be `open_dialog([object Object])`, which btw throws exactly that error (`Unexpected identifier`) if you try to execute it.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh! Sorry. Here is what setContent spits out: `<img style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="open_popUp([object Object]);" src="http://clients.frende.me/incognito/images/2012-9-17_930wcordovast.svg">`. Clearly `[object Object]` is not what I was anticipating…

Comment: omg, you're right. I guess I shouldn't work so late into night. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, `[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object and that's why creating JavaScript source code like this is not a good idea. You have two possibilities: Either convert `flot_data` to  JSON and use that value instead (`+ JSON.stringify(flot_data) +`). This basically serialises your data and later, when the function is called is interpreted again as object (which is not really an ideal solution) or you make `flot_data` global and just put the name of the variable in the string: `onclick="open_popUp(flot_data);"`. This is not a great solution either though.

Comment: The best solution is to not use inline event handlers but bind them with JavaScript, so that you can assign actual functions with actual references to variables. But since I don't know about the context of your code, I cannot really suggest an approach how to do this here. I can only point you to general information: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that flot_data is *not* a JSON string; it has apparently already been parsed into a JavaScript object, maybe by the AJAX call that retrieved it.  You can't concatenate an object with a string and expect to see JSON; the language has no idea what its original format was, and can't convert it back.

You need to either use the raw JSON string and then parse it inside of open_dialog, or a much better idea would be to avoid the inline handler altogether, and attach the click listener in your script, using jQuery's `.click(function)`.